# Format Financial Data like "2,000" as "2M" using a custom Format String with C# .NET WinForms and WPF Applications

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, string, format

We'd like to know if there is a way to format financial data such as "2,000" and "2,000,000" as "2M" and "2MM" respectively - essentially replacing the 1000's with M's.

Ideally there would be a format string we could use, such that 2000.0.ToString("X") would give us "2M" back and vice versa. Does such a formatstring exist? If not - is it possible to create one?

Note that these format strings work:

```
#,#,M – this will convert 2,000 to 2M (and back)
#,#,,MM – this will convert 2,000,00 to 2MM (and back)
#,#,,,B – this will convert 2,000,000,000 to 2B (and back)
```

However we need something more dynamic - something that can detect if it's any of these values and can apply the appropriate format string, if possible.

Comment: You're going to need to identify more cases. For example, does "2,001" throw an exception, return "2,001" or return "2M"?

Comment: Hi Bob - in this case we'd like to show it as 2.001M. We want the number of M's to be controlled be scale - i.e. if it's 1000, 1M, 10,000, 10M, 1234 as 1.234M, and so on.

Comment: @GauravSharma so could you just devide the amount by 1000 in a loop and add an m untill it reach the first place holder ie 1000/1000 = 1M 1,000,000/1000/1000 = 1MM

Comment: @caseyr547 a bit tricker, since we're simply assigned this format string to our vendor grid as follows:   ultraGridColumn.Format = "#,#,M"; - this works, but doesn't cope with the variations, i.e. if we put in 1,000,000, it gives us 1,000M, not 1MM

Comment: @Gaurav would you want to display 1,000,001 as 1.000001MM ? Do you have a maximum number of significant digits in mind?

Comment: Our user is flexible in this regard - whatever is more intuitive/makes more sense :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a format to achieve what you want. You can, however, implement your own with the interfaces [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) and [`ICustomFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter.aspx) and pass this into the `Format()` and `ToString()` calls.